# Remember the data in In-App purchase in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I made an app that has only 1 In-App purchase and when you buy it - it removes the Ads.
How can I make the app "remember" that the user purchased it?

For example, I want to `isPremium` to become `true` when the user purchased it, but every time I log in the app the `isPremium` is not `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to store a value that corresponds to the purchase of your IAP.

In this example we use `NSUserDefaults` to check if a key, `removeAds`, is `true` or `false`. The `if` statement will always execute until you set your key to `true`. For more information on `NSUserDefaults` please refer to [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/).

```
// Create this globally
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

// Check if IAP has been purchased
if !defaults.boolForKey("removeAds") {
    // IAP not purchased
    // Display ads
}

// Upon the successful purchase of your IAP you set the key to true
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "removeAds")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: Great, it works! thanks! BUT a short note: In iOS 8+ you don't have to use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()` anymore.

Comment: NSUserDefaults can be modified easyli by a potentially User who doesn't want to pay. I prefer the keychain which is encrypted.

Comment: @donmarkusi a user could easily put their phone in airplane mode also so ads are not received. I think its safe to say the majority of iPhone users would not go through that much trouble modifying the `NSUserDefaults` to avoid a $0.99 purchase.